# JS can't get my true/false function to display the false output only the true output

Tags: javascript

I need to write a good that will validate if a number is in between a range of two numbers I can only get the number is valid output no matter what i input in my text box.

```
 function validInputRange(min, max, textbox) {
     if (textbox >= min && textbox <= max) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 }
 function btnValidate_onclick() {
     // assign textbox elements to variables for easier access
     var numberTextbox = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
     var input = parseFloat(numberTextbox.value);
     var output = validInputRange(1, 49, numberTextbox.value);
     if (output = true) {
         var answer = "valid";
         numberTextbox.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
     } else {
         answer = "false";
         numberTextbox.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
     }
     numberTextbox.value = answer;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `var output = validInputRange(1,49,input)` ?

Comment: tried it and no matter what i input I always get a valid output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (output = true)
```

Just do

```
if (output)
```

or

```
if (output == true)
```

`=` is used for assignment, while `==` or `===` for comparing.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you thank you that did it man I feel so stupid

Comment: @user2966448 no problem, it's a common mistake :) please check the answer as accepted if the solution was useful.